# Angular Directive for svg data through URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, directive

I want to create a angular directive by which I can get svg data. For now I have the following directive -- (the following one is working fine)

```
    svgData.directive('myMap', function($http) {
        console.log("In directive");
        return {
            restrict: 'EAC',         
            templateUrl: 'path_name/myMap.tmpl.html',
            replace: true,
            scope: {                
                data: '='            
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {                                                                   
                  console.log(scope, element, attrs);                    
            }
        };
    });
```

In th myMap.tmpl.html, I can import the svg file the following way --

```
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="http://localhost:8080/data/svg/myMap.svg"></embed>
```

On the server side-- the route of the file

```
 app.get(api + '/data/svg/:fileName', mySvg.getSVGData);


 this.getSVGData = function(req, res) {
    var fs = require('fs')
     , filename = 'path_name'+req.params.fileName;
     console.log('Getting file', filename);
     res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"image/svg+xml"});
     fs.readFile(filename, "utf8", function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
        }
        res.write(data);
        console.log(data);  
        res.send(filename);        
    res.end();
    });             
}
```

Now I don't want to give the url directly on my template. I want to do something like `src={{scope}}` or `<my-map src="{{scope}}"></my-map>`

Any suggestion.

Comment: did you solved this?

Comment: May be not... long time !!!

Answer (score 0):

I was going to recommend using ng-src to do exactly what you wanted, but apparently there is an issue with that and embed not updating correctly.

Take a look at the last post here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/339

His directive would allow you to do what you wanted. Just use it in the tempalate and replace {{url}} with the scope variable that has your url.

```
<embed embed-src="{{url}}" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>
```